# Why did Hanuman say that he can't liberate himself from Indrajit's Brahmastra?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, indrajit

When Indrajit fired Brahmastra towards Hanuman, Hanuman say he has no capacity to liberate himself from Brahmastra. Here is the quote from [Sundara Kanda Sarga 48](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga48/sundara_48_frame.htm).

> "I have no capacity to liberate from the bondage of the missile due to
> the power of Brahma the father of the world. Thus knowing the bondage,
> through the missile presided over by Brahma the self-born creator
> imposed by the enemy, it must be obeyed by me."

But just before Hanuman entered Lanka, Jambavanta reminded him that Brahma gave him a boon of indestructibility from any kind of missile. This is what Jambavanta told to Hanuman as per [Kishkinda Kanda Sarga 66](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga66/kishkindha_66_frame.htm).

> "Oh, chivalric warrior at war, while the Air-god is being supplicated,
> oh, dear boy, Brahma gave you a boon decreeing your 'indestructibility
> by any missile...'

So inspite of having a boon of not getting harmed by any weapons, why Hanuman said he has no capacity to liberate himself from Brahmastra?

Comment: Translation as per Gita Press: “I have no capacity to liberate from the bondage of the missile due to the power of Brahma the father of the world”- knowing like this Indrajit has bound me. I must obey this bondage to respect Brahmaji. ।। Also read the previous verse which says Hanuman remembers his boon. And verse 42-43 after this translation.

Comment: Any boon given by a divinity becomes a "brahma vãkya (ब्रह्म वाक्य), and as such, to maintain the sanctity of tapas (तपस), sãdhnã (साधना) and righteousness, all forms of divinity generally obey by the rules of the given boon or weapons or curse, even if they are capable of voiding and nulling any kind of boon or curse or weapons, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lord Hanuman is a very humble devotee of Lord Rama. He can surpass any weapon of material potency. The Ramayana in the verses folllowed by this particular verse quoted here (O.P. )  explain this itself in Sril Valmiki variant of the Book.

But, here Sri Ramacharitmanas precisely clears that since He was on a duty of Lord Rama He could have easily neutralized the "Brahmastra" weapon but He thought that it could mitigate the values of the weapon. So, He opted to get captured instead.

This has been mentioned in the
**Ramachitamanas** by Sril Tulsidas Pundit in the **SUNDERKAND** **Doha(verse)#19** as:

> > **Brahmaastra tehi sadha, Kapi mann kinhi vichaar |**
> > **Jo na Brahmasar maanhu, Mahima mitt hi apaar ||19||**

**Translation:** Meghanaad (Indrajit) ultimately fitted to his bow the weapon/arrow known as Brahmaastra (weapon presided over by Lord Brahma), when Lord Hanuman thought within Himself; "If I submit not to Brahma's own weapon, it's infinite glory will be cast to the winds".

[image]

Comment: you are right Ramcharitanamans is right here